# Javascript Adding Values Together

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add two values together e.g. 14.0 + 2.1 = 16.1 but I keep on getting them added onto each other e.g 14.0 + 2.1 = 14.02.1

```
var miledistance = miledistance1 + miledistance2;
```

Comment: It's obviously Javascript and not Java.

Comment: Perhaps you are using Javascript which is not the same as Java.

Comment: 1/ javascript, not java
2/ to add vs. to concatenate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Java:

Make sure they are both float values.
Try casting:

```
miledistance = (float) miledistance1 + (float) miledistance2;
```

Or use [`Float.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

```
miledistance = Float.valueOf(miledistance1) + Float.valueOf(miledistance2);
```

---

For Javascript:

```
miledistance = parseFloat(miledistance1) + parseFloat(miledistance2);
```

---

*NOTE*: Java and  javascript are **not** the same language.

Comment: OPs problem looks like string concatenation; could you change the Java example to something parsing the string (say, `Float.valueOf(...)` instead of the cast)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the program is treating them as strings, cast them as float or double.